# Prevent zip from adding subdirectory 'names'

Tags: shell-script, zip

When I run the command `zip arch.zip *`, intending to add only the files in the pwd and none of its subdirectories, I instead get an archive containing all the files and all the subdirectories of the pwd although inside the archive the added subdirectories do not have any files in them. Clearly `-r` would be used to populate those subdirectories, but how do I prevent the empty subdirectories from being added to the archive at all?

Please note that the command is being run from a Bash script and I can not simply exclude any subdirectories by name because I won't know in advance which subdirectories will be present.

Surely I don't have to write a routine in the script to loop through the directory's files, individually adding them based on their file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-D` option:

```
zip -D arch.zip *
```

This tells `zip` not to create entries for directories.

Comment: Thanks. That'll teach me to search the man more accurately, using `subdir` as the search term failed me.